# Trigger background service ExecuteAsync method in .Net core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, console-application

I am creating console application in asp.net core which is going to run as background service in different environments. I have used "**BackgroundService**" class provided by "**Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting**". I want to run its  "**ExecuteAsync**" method when my program gets started.

File: Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                  .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                  {
                  })
                  .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                  {
                      services.AddHostedService<IHostedService,RabbitLister>();

                  })
                 .UseConsoleLifetime()
                 .Build();


        }
```

File: RabbitLister.cs

```
public class RabbitLister : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IEventBus _eventBus;
        private readonly ILogger<RabbitLister> _logger;

        public RabbitLister()
        {
        }

        public RabbitLister(IEventBus eventBus, ILogger<RabbitLister> logger)
        {
            _eventBus = eventBus;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _eventBus.SubscribeDynamic("myQueue");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: after you build the host call `host.Run()` that will start hosted service and eventually call the execute function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the host has been build, invoke `host.Run()`

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var host = new HostBuilder()
          .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => {
          })
          .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
              services.AddHostedService<IHostedService, RabbitLister>();
          })
         .UseConsoleLifetime()
         .Build();

    //run the host
    host.Run();
}
```

that will start hosted service and eventually call the execute function