# Can I use BackgroundService in dot net core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know how to use background service in asp.net core

```
public class WatchMan : BackgroundService
{
    
}
```

I have a dot core console application which I want to run as window service, can I use `BackgroundService` or something similar there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just be sure to keep the main thread alive so the application does not exit.

This article seems to explain the process decently;
https://medium.com/@daniel.sagita/backgroundservice-for-a-long-running-work-3debe8f8d25b

And here's an SO that shows the process aswell:

[Trigger background service ExecuteAsync method in .Net core console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903147/trigger-background-service-executeasync-method-in-net-core-console-application)

Also if you want to do some background processing, take a look at hangfire:

https://www.hangfire.io/

Which can also be ran from a windows service.